# Canvas border color change on touch with canvas object

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to print design on the canvas with in the borders,if the canvas object is scaled or resized to beyond the border,canvas border color should change to red color or show some message .

If the canvas object touches or crosses the border of canvas how to change the border color.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is old but I just happen to be working on this same problem (just changing the color) here is what i did  and hopefully it will help someone else with the same problem

http://jsfiddle.net/Lfqdj5hu/1/

the fiddle wasent working with jquery for some reason so this is a quick attempt

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('demo');



canvas.setWidth(600);
canvas.setHeight(500);

canvas.on({
      'object:moving':boundingBox,
      'object:scaling':boundingBox,
      'object:rotating':boundingBox,
    });

function boundingBox(bbox){
    // detecting sides of the canvas
    if(bbox.target.getWidth() + bbox.target.left > canvas.width
       || bbox.target.getHeight() + bbox.target.top > canvas.height 
       || bbox.target.top < 0 
       || bbox.target.left < 0){
        //$('#demo').css('box-shadow', '0 0 20px red');
        var cd = document.getElementById('demo');
        var cdStyle = cd.style;
        cdStyle.backgroundColor = 'red';
    } else {
        //$('#demo').css('box-shadow'. '0 0 20px #a8a8a8');
        var cd = document.getElementById('demo');
        var cdStyle = cd.style;
        cdStyle.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
}



var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'blue',
  width: 50,
  height: 50
});

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 95, 
  fill: 'green', 
  left: 175, 
  top: 200
});

canvas.add(rect);
canvas.add(circle);
```

i hope that someone finds this usefull

Answer (score 0):

See this example on the official website: http://fabricjs.com/intersection/ - Collisions can be detected with `intersectsWithObject()` function.

For your problem just check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FD53A/54/

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
    var obj = e.target;
    obj.setCoords();

    canvas.forEachObject(function (targ) {
        activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();

        if (targ === activeObject) return;


        if (Math.abs(activeObject.oCoords.tr.x - targ.oCoords.tl.x) < edgedetection) {
            activeObject.left = targ.left - activeObject.currentWidth;
        }
        if (Math.abs(activeObject.oCoords.tl.x - targ.oCoords.tr.x) < edgedetection) {
            activeObject.left = targ.left + targ.currentWidth;
        }
        if (Math.abs(activeObject.oCoords.br.y - targ.oCoords.tr.y) < edgedetection) {
            activeObject.top = targ.top - activeObject.currentHeight;
        }
        if (Math.abs(targ.oCoords.br.y - activeObject.oCoords.tr.y) < edgedetection) {
            activeObject.top = targ.top + targ.currentHeight;
        }
        if (activeObject.intersectsWithObject(targ) && targ.intersectsWithObject(activeObject)) {
            targ.strokeWidth = 10;
            targ.stroke = 'red';
        } else {
            targ.strokeWidth = 0;
            targ.stroke = false;
        }
        if (!activeObject.intersectsWithObject(targ)) {
            activeObject.strokeWidth = 0;
            activeObject.stroke = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I jus want to change the canvas border not the two objects collision,not the collision of two objects..can anyone reply